# Running an executable in compatibility mode through CMD

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8.1

What lines of code could be used in either CMD or .bat form to run an executable file in compatibility mode? 
Can it be done at all, or is it some registry wizardry?

Comment: Try this: [http://superuser.com/a/379402](http://superuser.com/a/379402)

Comment: Ran the code in the post, didn't work sadly... The link is for windows 7 but I am running windows 8. So that might have something to do with it...

Comment: Click `ctrl + R`, type `regedit` and then, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`. Here you can see executables with compatibility. Example: Some exe file, I've set compatibility with Windows 95, I've got `~ WIN95 DWM8And16BitMitigation`

Comment: Easily done, the executable in question isn't there though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to be Administrator or be in group of them.
Second, you need to know what kind of compatibility you are going to set (Windows 7, Windows XP, etc...)
Third, only applied for `.exe` files

I've set compatibility for Windows XP S3 for my `.exe` file
Open cmd line as Administrator.

Some example:

```
Windows 7         - ~ WIN7RTM
Windows XP SP3    - ~ WINXPSP3
Windows Vista SP1 - ~ VISTASP1
```

**Note:** This will be applied for all users

```
reg.exe Add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Users\****\Desktop\MPC-HC.1.7.10.x64.exe" /d "WINXPSP3"
```

**For current user only**

```
reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Users\****\Desktop\MPC-HC.1.7.10.x64.exe" /d "WINXPSP3"
```

I've got:
[image: Flag]

Comment: I manually added the executable to the registry to run in compatibility mode for Vista, XP and windows 7. But still really dosen't want to run. I appreciate your patience and help in the issue but I'm afraid i may not be able to fix this one :p. Thanks bruh.

Comment: Maybe your executable is not compatible at all... Share it to check

Comment: "This application is not compatible with the installed operating system.
Please upgrade to Windows 98SE, Windows 2000 or better."

Comment: I give you an example. Under which OS version your application is executable? In command line you do exatly what wizard offers you.

Comment: Apparently this game got bugged out and stopped working as soon as you upgraded to win 8.1. I've been looking for a fix and no matter what compatibility setting you put it in it still doesn't want to run.

Comment: So, the problem is only in game. Reed game's forum or reinstall